# htaccess error404 except one file

Tags: .htaccess

OK so yeah a weird one for sure.

Not something I would typically look to do as it typically doesn't make sense but a site I am working with has a script that deletes a file after it's been created and cached and only grabs data out of it if it exists. If it doesn't then the script moves on.

What I need to do is exclude resources.js from returning a 404 if it does not exist.

The file in question lives in examplefolder/resources.js and the current ht access is:

```html
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{https} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L] 
RewriteCond %{https_host} ^example.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
<FilesMatch "^(resources.js)$">
  ExpiresActive on 
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 month"
</FilesMatch>
```

Many thanks in advance for the help. I've searched every corner of the internet for the answer to this. Maybe it's time to finally buy a few books /courses on .htaccess

Comment: It is always questionable if you directly map requests to physical files in your servers file system, except for routing scripts. Instead of directly referencing that javascript file you could use a routing script to fetch the files content. That leaves you in full control of what you actually want to return if the file is missing without having to fiddle with the http servers configuration.

Comment: Another question is: if the file does _not_ exist, which appears to be an expected situation if I understand your question correctly, then what _do_ you want to return, if not a 404?

Comment: Hey, thanks for answering such a weird question. By a routing script do you mean with js? We are calling the cached version from the browser so as to get a var inside - the deleted one on the server would not contain the information I need - thus it's deleted after creation to avoid a mismatch. The logic of the code is that if the file does not exist then carry on, else if it does exist grab the unique var in question.

Comment: As far as what else could be returned instead of a 404, the honest answer is I don't know. I just need to avoid the errordocument being returned when the JS file is not found in cache.

Comment: Wouldn't http status 410 ("Gone") be the correct return code here? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Yes, that would be good. As long as it doesn't return the 404 document then that's a solution - unless it does exist in the cache in which case we want to return a 200.

Comment: A http status 200 has to send the actual object requested, be it a file or some information. If you want to use a http status 200 to signal that the file does exist or not, then this should not be done by the http server itself, since that is kind of counter intuitive, such logic should get implemented in a router script or similar. That is what I referred to before in my first comment when mentioning a router script delivering the file. That script can also send custom responses to the requesting client (your javascript logic) indicating if the file should get fetched from the cache or not.